# Get row values as column names in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datagridview

I  have a requirement to display row  values as column names in a data grid view.  I want to get the store names into columns using sql select statement. (Please refer the attached image). I want user to enter some values under each column. So STORE 1, STORE 2, STORE 3 should displays as columns in datagrid view. Does anyone can help me to get this work?

[image]

while googling i found this can be done using PIVOT in SQL. But in this table i don't have any aggregate columns. Any help pls?

the result should be somthing like
[image]

Comment: It's not at all clear where all of these magic numbers have come from, or what the logic is meant to be

Answer (score 1):

You may know that your data only contains a single row for each pivoting column, but SQL Server has to construct a plan that *could* accommodate multiple rows.

So, use [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and just use an aggregate that, if passed a single value, will return that same value. `MIN()` and `MAX()` fit that description (as does `SUM` if you're working with numeric data)

Comment: Could you please give me a sample query on that?

Comment: @Aruna - I don't know what your expected output is given your example data - I'm not sure what data you're expecting to appear in the `STORE 1`, `STORE 2` columns.

Comment: There are records which has item count. Say Item 01 has 20 qty. So i want user to distribute the qty for stores. Record set will look like follows:

ItemCode  | Qty   | Store 1 | Store 2 | Store 3| ...N |
001       | 20    | 10      | 10    
002       | 15    | 5       | 5       | 5      |

like wise

Comment: How 20 will be distributed among stores? is there specific logic? it seems a stored procedure will help you, pass the itemcode and storeid to it , and build the logic inside the sp, and return the qty?

Answer (score -1):

You may use specific function of dynamic pivot and pass your query with item count column.

You can use below link which provided you function and can easily show you expected output.

```
http://forums.asp.net/t/1772644.aspx/1
```

Procedure name:

```
[dbo].[dynamic_pivot]
```